# Remove excess whitespace from within a string

Tags: php, string

I receive a string from a database query, then I remove all HTML tags, carriage returns and newlines before I put it in a CSV file. Only thing is, I can't find a way to remove the **excess** white space from *between* the strings.

What would be the best way to remove the inner whitespace characters?

Comment: Please, post an sample of original string and wanted string.

Comment: Can you also clear up how the final output needs to be?  Are you inserting the commas into data for CSV, getting it from a database with commas already in it, feeding strings into a function that handles the CSV insertion, etc?

Comment: ok the final out put needs to be a string with each word seperated by a single whitespace, at the moment it is a multiple whitespaces.

Comment: @Joe, I would not waste time and would start giving credit to all those who've helped you before! :)

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want but here are two situations:

1. If you are just dealing with excess <kbd>whitespace</kbd> on the beginning or end of the string you can use `trim()`, `ltrim()` or `rtrim()` to remove it.
2. If you are dealing with extra spaces within a string consider a `preg_replace` of multiple <kbd>whitespaces</kbd> `" "*` with a single <kbd>whitespace</kbd> `" "`.

**Example:**

```
$foo = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $foo);
```

Comment: $foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo );

Comment: using the `$foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo );` will kill the effects of `nl2br()`

Comment: just use nl2br before using preg_replace and you should be good to go.

Comment: Typo/Escaper note - if the code does not remove extra whitespace for you - make sure you have "\" before "s" :) some online-php-testing pages remove it :)

Comment: This should be CSS safe, right?  As in, this would safely compress a variable holding a long, multi-line CSS string?

Answer (score 54):

```
$str = str_replace(' ','',$str);
```

Or, replace with underscore, & nbsp; etc etc.

Comment: This removes all whitespace. He just wants to normalise the string.

Comment: What I was looking for (even though it wasn't the question)

Comment: @Gigala "What would be the best way to remove the inner whitespace characters?" was the question. This answer satisfies that perfectly.

Comment: @CoryDee That's true, for that last single sentence. But in the introduction, the question is phrased as "**excess** whitespace", with emphasis on the excess. You ended up satisfying the OP's ACTUAL problem, so it doesn't much matter, but as long as we're getting *technical* about it...

Comment: This doesn't work if the **count** of _spaces_ is **even number**, let say: `Hi    Earth` with 4 _spaces_ in between will become: `HiEarth`. This doesn't solve my problem with relevant to the question.

Comment: `$str = str_replace('  ',' ',$str);` to remove excess spaces

Answer (score 34):

none of other examples worked for me, so I've used this one:

```
trim(preg_replace('/[\t\n\r\s]+/', ' ', $text_to_clean_up))
```

this replaces all tabs, new lines, double spaces etc to simple 1 space.

Comment: Thanks, @wp78de but for any reason, I had issues with just `\s+`. Though it was back in 2014 so maybe it is changed, haven't touched PHP for the last 3 years, can't comment but will leave current answer while it was a solution and may still be in some cases.

Answer (score 28):

`$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $str));`

The above line of code will remove *extra* spaces, as well as leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to replace only multiple spaces in a string, for Example: `"this string                        have lots of                        space  .   "`
And you expect the answer to be 
`"this string have lots of space"`, you can use the following solution:

```
$strng = "this string                        have lots of                        space  .   ";

$strng = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $strng));

echo $strng;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
$str = trim(str_replace("  ", " ", $str));
```

This **removes extra whitespaces from both sides** of string and **converts two spaces to one** within the string. Note that this won't convert three or more spaces in a row to one!
Another way I can suggest is using implode and explode that is safer but totally not optimum!

```
$str = implode(" ", array_filter(explode(" ", $str)));
```

My suggestion is using a native for loop or using regex to do this kind of job.

Comment: This doesn't convert multiple spaces correctly where the space is longer than two spaces.

Answer (score 3):

There are security flaws to using preg_replace(), if you get the payload from user input [or other untrusted sources]. PHP executes the regular expression with eval(). If the incoming string isn't properly sanitized, your application risks being subjected to **code injection**.

In my own application, instead of bothering sanitizing the input (and as I only deal with short strings), I instead made a slightly more processor intensive function, though which is secure, since it doesn't eval() anything.

```
function secureRip(string $str): string { /* Rips all whitespace securely. */
  $arr = str_split($str, 1);
  $retStr = '';
  foreach ($arr as $char) {
    $retStr .= trim($char);
  }
  return $retStr;
}
```

Comment: It only executes it using eval if you specify the 'e' modifyier: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval
it has also it says that
"This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.5.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0." So you can't eval stuff in preg_replace anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Sandip’s answer, I had a bunch of strings showing up in the logs that were mis-coded in bit.ly. They meant to code just the URL but put a twitter handle and some other stuff after a space. It looked like this

```
? productID =26%20via%20@LFS
```

Normally, that would‘t be a problem, but I’m getting a lot of SQL injection attempts, so I redirect anything that isn’t a valid ID to a 404. I used the preg_replace method to make the invalid productID string into a valid productID.

```
$productID=preg_replace('/[\s]+.*/','',$productID);
```

I look for a space in the URL and then remove everything after it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 9.7 intruduced the new `Str::squish()` method to remove extraneous whitespaces including extraneous white space between words: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-squish

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "I      am a PHP   Developer";
$str_length = strlen($str);
$str_arr = str_split($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $str_length; $i++) {
   if (isset($str_arr[$i + 1])  && $str_arr[$i] == ' ' && $str_arr[$i] == $str_arr[$i + 1]) {
       unset($str_arr[$i]);
   } 
   else {
     continue;
   }
}
echo implode("", $str_arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote recently a simple function which removes excess white space from string without regular expression `implode(' ', array_filter(explode(' ', $str)))`.

Comment: This will also destroy any false strings (that shouldn't be destroyed) like `0`.