# Remove WhiteSpace in PHP

Tags: php, curl, whitespace

I'm dealing with some excessive white space that I want to remove. An example:

```
Envelopes/Env. Thick/Env. Thin      0 pages


Label      0 pages


Hagaki      0 pages



Replace Count


Drum Unit      0


Toner      0
```

I've  tried to use `preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $content);` but the outcome is not what I expected. The output with preg_replace:
`Envelopes/Env. Thick/Env. Thin 0 pages Label 0 pages Hagaki 0 pages Replace Count Drum Unit 0 Toner 0`

What I want:

> Envelopes/Env. Thick/Env. Thin 0 pages  
>   Label 0 pages 
>   Hagaki 0 pages 
>   Replace Count Drum Unit 0 
>   Toner 0

My code:

```
<?php

$cw=curl_init("http://192.168.1.135/printer/maininfo.html");
$txtfl=fopen("printermtpage.txt","w");

curl_setopt($cw, CURLOPT_FILE, $txtfl);
curl_setopt($cw, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_exec($cw);

curl_close($cw);

$file="printermtpage.txt";
$txtopentoread=fopen("printermtpage.txt","r");
$txtread=fread($txtopentoread,filesize($file));

$notags=strip_tags(html_entity_decode($txtread));
$remblanks=preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $notags);

fclose($txtfl);

?>
```

Comment: Why not edit the original page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/php-remove-whitespace-from-within-a-string</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegEx `\s` matches `[\r\n\f\t\v ]` and since you don't need newlines removed (or others in the class) you could use:

```
$remblanks=preg_replace('/[ \t]+/',' ',$notags);
```

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/tS0vG7

### Update

Advanced RegEx that strips 2+ whitespace characters:

```
preg_replace('/(?|([ \t]){2,}|(?:\r?(\n)){2,})/','\1',$notags);
```

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/nU4fU2

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `\s` matches newline characters (`\n`) as well. So you're converting your newlines to spaces, effectively putting them all on one line.

Try using [`\[:blank:\]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) to match only spaces and tabs.