# PHP - Remove excess Whitespace but not new lines

Tags: php, regex, newline, whitespace, trim

i was looking for a way to remove excess whitespaces from within a string (that is, if 2 or more spaces are next each other, leave only 1 and remove the others), i found this [Remove excess whitespace from within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-whitespace-from-within-a-string) and i wanted to use this solution:

```
$foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo );
```

but this removes new lines aswell, while i want to keep them. 
Is there any way to keep newlines while removing excess whitespace?

Comment: Replace `\s` with a space ? If you also want to remove tabs then use `/[\t ]+/`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php
defines `\h any horizontal whitespace character (since PHP 5.2.4)`
so probably you are looking for

```
$foo = preg_replace( '/\h+/u', ' ', $foo );
```

or you can explicitly list all characters you want to affect

```
$foo = preg_replace( '/\t +/', ' ', $foo );
```

Comment: I assume it's wrong because for me it removed all whitespace :)

Comment: For preserving newlines you can do a workaround, like splitting all string by newline into array, cleaning each part and imploding again by newline

Answer (score 6):

If some of your symbols were converted to � after `preg_replace` (for example, Cyrillic capital letter **R** / Р), use `mb_ereg_replace` instead of `preg_replace`:

```
$value = mb_ereg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $value);
```

Comment: using u modifier for preg_replace is enough

Answer (score 5):

if you want to remove excess of only-spaces (not tabs, new-lines, etc) you could use HEX code to be more specific:

```
    $text = preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $text);
```

Comment: There's a lot of space characters that are not the ASCII 32 (`\x20`) space.