# Remove double space and space after line break from String

Tags: php, regex

so, first i have this input

```php
$string = "Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example3";
```

and then i want to remove the url from the `$string` using regex

```php
$string = preg_replace('/[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/', '', $string);
```

after i removed all of the url from the string, the output will be

```php
Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
 elit  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

the problem is, there is double space and i want to make it more neat

ive tried using this, which will replaced all the double space with single space

```php
$string = preg_replace('/\x20+/', ' ', $string);
```

and theres come another problem which is theres a space after line break

```
Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
 elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

and it makes me uncomfortable.

i need a solution to get rid of the url, but also makes it neat.
the last result I want is like this

```
Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

*sorry if its looks weird, thanks*

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove all the URL's.

Use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove any left over spaces

Again, use `preg_replace()` to remove any dubble spaces. ([regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725894/php-remove-excess-whitespace-but-not-new-lines))

Then, to remove any spaces that accrued at the beginning of the line, replace those with nothing to remove them.

```php
<?php

    $r = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
    $string = "Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example3";

    // Remove url's
    $clean = preg_replace($r, ' ', $string);

    // Trim whitespaces
    $clean = trim($clean);

    // Replace dubble-space with single space
    $clean = preg_replace( '/\h+/', ' ', $clean);

    // Remove any spaces after newline
    $clean = preg_replace('/^ /m', '', $clean);

    // Show result
    echo $clean;
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

[Try online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e40d1b39b8b2f00b45c68303e638bc6ab2f547c)

---

**Note:** This could be a lot simplified by combining some calls, I chose not to so the steps are more clear

Answer (score 1):

I would use those regex :

```php
$string = "Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example3";

$string = preg_replace('/[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)([ ]*)?/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/(([ ]*)?(\r\n|\n)([ ]*)?)/', "\r\n", $string); # Remove any potantial space before line break and remove any potential space after line break

echo $string;
```

Output

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

Note : I just added `([ ]*)?` to the regex that match urls to be sure to also match spaces after urls