# mysql remove white space

Tags: php, mysql, whitespace

I read on the forum about php function LTRIM, I used it in my code but still getting white space on the left side of the text, here is an example of my code, anyone could tell me what's wrong with the LTRIM function below?

```
$sql = "UPDATE content SET text = LTRIM('$content21') WHERE element_id = '21' ";
```

Comment: why dont you clean/trim the value before entering it in the sql?

Comment: I would have used php for this

Comment: '21' is not character , shd be with out Quote

Comment: @Bhavin, thanks I will try without quotes

Comment: @Jonathan, I have white space on the left side of the text when the text is saved to DB, I read that LTRIM would fix the issue...

Comment: @Mr. Alien, please could you explain? this is php, I just did not include the <?php ?> in the sample code above

Comment: $content21 = trim($content21); OR $content21 = ltrim($content21);

Comment: @Michel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-whitespace-from-within-a-string

Comment: Yes this is PHP but I think @Mr.Alien think its an SQL function. because its in your query.

Comment: @Michel, check the answers below and see what i ment, with trimming the value before  entering it in the sql query.

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks for the pointers, I would not know how to make it work in: $foo = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $foo );

Comment: @Michel that's a regex

Answer (score 0):

Try to trim before the query like

```
$content21 = ltrim($content21);
$sql = "UPDATE content SET text = '$content21' WHERE element_id = '21' ";
```

Comment: That wont work either. You are not refering to `$content21`'s value but `$content21` as a string itself

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE `content` SET `text` = LTRIM('".$content21."') WHERE `element_id` = 21 ";
```

extract the var from string

edit based on comment, as there are tons of solutions for that:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `content` SET `text` = LTRIM('".htmlspecialchars($content21, ENT_QUOTES)."') WHERE `element_id` = 21 ";
```

Comment: This wont work LTRIM is a php function you need to take the function out too. See my answer

Comment: There is an LTRIM function in mysql.

Comment: @Michel also pay attention to the quotation.

Comment: @de_nuit thanks I used copy/paste, yeah I noticed the quotation are different, there is still a white space in the DB before the text

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE content SET text = ".ltrim($content21)." WHERE element_id = '21'";
```

Comment: It removes all the text after the ' so for instance I tried test's 123, in the DB, there is only: test

Comment: Also, it does remove the white space but it removes all the text after the apostrophe '

Comment: Well this is exactly what `ltrim()` does it trim the left part of the string.

Comment: If you want to remove only the spaces you could use `$sql = "UPDATE content SET text = ".str_replace(" ", "", $content21)." WHERE element_id = 21";`

Comment: I thought the ltrim removes white space only? It removes any sentences after an apostrophe ' inside the DB so for instance "john's hat" is saved as "john" in the db

Comment: What I wanted to say is that `ltrim($str, $char)` only remove from the left of the file and it does'nt remove only whitespaces you can Specified characters to be removed.

Comment: And your `'` is marking the end of the sql string you'll have to use another function to take care of the `'` in `"John's"`.

Comment: or you could use `ltrim($content21, "'");`