# PHP trim() doesn't work well

Tags: php

`trim()` doesnt't work, I have no idea why. I adding model is not important, sorry for the first add.

When I run it and load row with `123 123 123` from Excel, this doesn't make me `123123123`

How can I fix it?

If you will need the model, please write a comment.

**PHP a bit controller**

```
class Kontroler extends CI_Controller {

    public function upload()
    {
        $file = 'przyklad kk.xls';
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $this->excel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);  
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $array = $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

        for ($i = 2; $i <= count($array); $i++) {
            if ($array[$i]['A'] == NULL) $array[$i]['A'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['B'] == NULL) $array[$i]['B'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['C'] == NULL) $array[$i]['C'] = '00-000';
            if ($array[$i]['F'] == NULL) $array[$i]['F'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['G'] == NULL) $array[$i]['G'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['D'] == NULL) $array[$i]['D'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['H'] == NULL) $array[$i]['H'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['E'] == NULL) $array[$i]['E'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['J'] == NULL) $array[$i]['J'] = 'Brak';
            if ($array[$i]['I'] == NULL) $array[$i]['I'] = 'brak@brak.pl';
            if ($array[$i]['N'] == NULL) $array[$i]['N'] = 'Brak';

            $tab[$i]['City'] = $array[$i]['D'];
            $tab[$i]['ContactPersonName'] = $array[$i]['F'];
            $tab[$i]['ContactPersonSubname'] = $array[$i]['G'];
            $tab[$i]['Email'] = $array[$i]['I'];
            $tab[$i]['Name'] = $array[$i]['A'];
            $tab[$i]['Phone'] = $array[$i]['H'];
            $tab[$i]['PostCode'] = $array[$i]['C'];
            $tab[$i]['Potential'] = $array[$i]['J'];
            $tab[$i]['Powiat'] = $array[$i]['E'];
            $tab[$i]['Street'] = $array[$i]['B'];
            $tab[$i]['ID_GR'] = $array[$i]['L'];
            $tab[$i]['ID_RM'] = $array[$i]['M'];
            $tab[$i]['ID_PR'] = $array[$i]['N'];    

            $Name = trim($array[$i]['A']);
            $Street = trim($array[$i]['B']);
            $PostCode = trim($array[$i]['C']);
            $City = trim($array[$i]['D']);
            $ContactPersonName = trim($array[$i]['F']);
            $ContactPersonSubname = trim($array[$i]['G']);
            $Email = trim($array[$i]['I']);
            $Name = trim($array[$i]['D']);
            $Phone = trim($tab[$i]['Phone']);
            $Powiat = trim($array[$i]['E']);
            $Potential = trim($array[$i]['J']);         
            $ID_GR = trim($tab[$i]['ID_GR']);
            $ID_RM = trim($array[$iQ]['M']);
            $ID_PR = trim($array[$i]['N']);             
        }
        $this->model->insert_from_file_kk($tab);
    }

    public function show()
    {
        $data['rekordy'] = $this->model->get_rek();
        $this->load->view('widok', $data);
    }
}
```

**PHP view**

```
<div id="content">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Nazwa</td><td>Ulica</td><td>Kod pocztowy</td><td>Miasto</td><td>Powiat</td><td>Imie os kontaktowej</td><td>Nazwisko os kontaktowej</td><td>Telefon</td><td>Email</td>     <td>Potencjal</td>
<td>ID_PR</td><td>ID_GR</td><td>ID_RM</td>
</tr>
<?php

foreach ($rekordy as $rekord)
{
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>$rekord->Name</td>
    <td>$rekord->Street</td>
    <td>$rekord->PostCode</td>
    <td>$rekord->City</td>
    <td>$rekord->Powiat</td>
    <td>$rekord->ContactPersonName</td>
    <td>$rekord->ContactPersonSubname</td>
    <td>$rekord->Phone</td>
    <td>$rekord->Email</td>
    <td>$rekord->Potential</td>
    <td>$rekord->ID_PR</td>
    <td>$rekord->ID_GR</td>
    <td>$rekord->ID_RM</td>
    </tr>
";

}

?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking here nor what the issue is. Please try to re-word your post so that people may understand how to help. If you can, include sample data and the expected output.

Comment: What is the value of $array[$i] before the trim functions? What is the output of the PHP view after?

Comment: Well `$Name` would never magically become an object variable, so you're only setting it as a variable?

Comment: Seems to work OK from what I can see in your code.

Comment: I fix as that was possible, check now please

Comment: You expect `trim` to turn "123 123 123" into "123123123"? Why? Does the manual say it would do that anywhere?

Comment: I load this from excel document where I have thousands numbers, its a bit hard. I want only to remove spaces

Comment: Then why are you using `trim`?

Comment: If you have better idea tell me

Comment: Idea: Use the search (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+spaces+from+string+%5Bphp%5D) to find other questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-excess-whitespace-from-within-a-string) that deal with the topic and settle on a solution using `str_replace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I run it and load row with 123 123 123 from excel this dont make me 123123123.

That's what `trim($str)` is supposed to do: stripping whitespaces from the beginning and end of `$str`. Attention: only whitespace from the beginning and end. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

To achieve what you want, simply replace all spaces with an empty string:

```
$subject = "123 123 123";
$output = str_replace(" ", "", $subject);
echo $output;
```

It outputs

> 123123123

Answer (score 1):

I might be way off here, but it looks like you have forgotten to wrap your PHP code in PHP tags:

```
<td><?php echo $rekord->Name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rekord->Street; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rekord->PostCode; ?></td>
```

Comment: Or just wrap them in curly braces: `<td>{$rekord->Name}</td>` since they're in double quotes.