# Removing unwanted whitespace in sub string in php?

Tags: php, string, explode

I've Scenario where user type a string in search box. If the entered string reaches more than one word, i explode it by using,

```
$text = "Hello World";
$pieces = explode(' ', $text);
```

and i will get the first and second term by

```
$pieces['0'] & $pieces['1'].
```

But, if an user type something like,

```
$text = "Hello                    World";
```

how should i get the second term?

If i `var_dump` the results, i'm getting

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(0) ""
  [11]=>
  string(5) "World"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove excess whitespace from within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-excess-whitespace-from-within-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `explode()` use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and then use `\s+` (**\s** space, **+** 1 or more times) as delimiter. Like this:

```
$pieces = preg_split("/\s+/", $text);
```

Comment: how can i do the same in Jquery? is it possible using preg_split?

Comment: @user3289108 See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/650037/3933332 and just put these characters which you want in the character class (`[]`)

Answer (score 1):

Rizier123's answer is valid enough, but if you want to avoid using `preg_split` which uses regular expression checking, you could get your array with the empty strings and just remove all empty elements from it like so:

```
$text = "Hello      World";
$pieces = array_filter(explode(' ', $text));
```

Answer (score 0):

replace multiple spaces with single space by using this

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $text);
```

then split the text

```
$pieces = explode(' ', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
<?php
$text = "Hello World";

// BONUS: remove whitespace from beginning and end of string

$text = trim($text);

// replace all whitespace with single space

$text = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $text);
$pieces = explode(' ', $text);
?>
```