# PHP IMAP How to get just the text-part of body? Not the different <html> tags etc

Tags: php, html, parsing, imap

I'm trying to write a script that downloads email from an exchange server and later inserts that into an database, but I'm having trouble getting the 'text part' of the emails in a good way.

`phpcode`

```
<?PHP
$user = "email@domain.com";
$password = "password123";
$mbox = imap_open("{exchange01:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", $user, $password);

$message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,1,1);

print_r($message);

if($mbox)
{
    imap_close($mbox);
};
?>
```

and the entire html body gets printed. I guess thats to be expected, but I'd like to not have the

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Verdana;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Neo Sans Std";}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#0563C1;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#954F72;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.E-postmall17
```

....mumbojumbo, just the text in the email itself (I can live with having signature and images and this and that).

Is there no easier way than somewhat roughly cutting the long string up at `<body...` to `</body...` and then cutting it further from there? There must be other people who've wanted to solve the same problem but I'm unable to find any answer after spending an entire day trying to solve it and google:ing it.

I guess in the end I'll just insert the entire htmlresponse into the database cell and hope for the best, but I'd rather not.

*Help me, Stackoverflow. You're my only hope*

**Solution edit:**

Not the exact solution I would've liked, but it does work (with some slight fixing to do).

```
echo strip_tags($message, '<body>');
```

Outputs just the

```
<body...>
Yayh the text i want!
</body .....>
```

part. Thanks alot @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs (In comments)

**Edit:**

In the end the code became roughly this

```
<?PHP
$user = "email@domain.com";
$password = "password";
$mbox = imap_open("{exchange01:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", $user, $password);

$message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,1,1);

$message = strip_tags($message, '<body>');
$message = explode(">", $message);
$message = explode("<", $message[1]);
$message = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $message[0]);
$message = html_entity_decode($message);
$message = trim($message);
//Or the above three combined in one row
#$message = trim(html_entity_decode( str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $message[0])));

echo $message;

if($mbox)
{
    imap_close($mbox);
};
?>
```

Which removes the first `<body something something something>` and the `</body>` at the end and after that removes the whitespace in the beginning and end of the variable. (Which @Goose also kinda answered in his edited answer below). It also converts html-encoded 'letters to the corresponding ones as well as removes the &nbsp tags and such.

Comment: do you not store the body content (the text) separate from the email code?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs hm? As far as i know `imap_fetchbody($mbox,1,1);` is the correct way to download mailbody and what gets downloaded is what you can see above (+more html text and then finaly some <body> YAYH THE TEXT I WANT (with some more html crap) </body>.

Comment: I more mean, if you store $body in a variable, then you have everything between the <body> tags, then you can use `strip_tags` to get rid of the rest

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Ohh..! Just what i was looking for, thanks a bunch! Been pulling my hair over this problem for hours xD

Comment: :) no worries :D haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `strip_tags()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$html = '<div>hello</div>';
$text = strip_tags($html);
echo $text; // hello
```

If you need to remove excess white space from the resulting string, use this. This will also remove new lines. Credit to [Remove excess whitespace from within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-excess-whitespace-from-within-a-string)

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
```

Comment: Yup, sure does solve the problem (besides lots of whitespace before and after the <body> tags). Not the 'perfect' solution but more than well enough.

Comment: @Tamazin I edited the question to all address how to handle excess white space.

Comment: Yeah i did it it with trim and also exploded the string to remove the start <body..> part and the ending </body>. Now i just need it to properly encode my swedish åäö letters and perhaps remove the &nbsp etc., thingies and I'm a happy coder ;D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

do 
`$message = imap_fetchbody($mbox,1,1.1);`

will give you the plain text part of the message not the entire body contents or use 1.2 if you want the html part

(empty) - Entire message
0 - Message header
1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
1.2 - TEXT/HTML
2 - MESSAGE/RFC822 (entire attached message)
2.0 - Attached message header
2.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
2.2 - TEXT/HTML
2.3 - file.ext

as per the 2nd comment on http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php it also had some nice functions in there for dynamically calculating the available message parts for you so you don't have to worry too much about what type of message and data it is.

Comment: Unfortenately that doesn't work.

With an email message that only has a text body and does not have any mime attachments, imap-fetchbody() will return the following for each requested part number:

(empty) - Entire message
0 - Message header
1 - Body text

The message is this way so i only got 0 or 1 to choose from (1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.2 etc. won't work). Even though the email has an png image and some this and that (regular mail with signature etc.).

Comment: if I were you i'd loop through the available parts and check that as there's very few mail clients that won't provide a) mime and b) split html out to plain text body part anyway

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work.

Using: $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $email_number);

I can see three [parts], first being the text (in html) and the two others being two PNGs. I'm using outlook to send email to an regular exchange2010 server. Would of course prefer to just get the "plain text" instead of html and then formatting it to my liking.. buuut didn't get that to work :(

Comment: strange because outlook by default makes a plain text copy of anything you type in the html box and always (again by default) makes them multipart mime emails in the old days it caused so much issues with email bloat as outlook emails were huge compared to proper email clients.

Comment: Yeah i figured modern version of outlook would do that but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.Have to investigate that further. If i manage to find why then the fix will be easy (download plaintext instead).

Comment: check outlook settings I don't have it installed on this machine as I use linux but i'm sure there's an option in outlook which you could probably set via GPO if you wanted to set it across the company wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can get email body into plain text with below detail:

```
$ClearText = preg_replace( "/\n\s+/", "\n", rtrim(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($body))) );
```