# how to use only "loop" to remove all excessive spaces in the sentence, without using string trimming functions and tring replacement functions?

Tags: php

In PHP, I am try to use "loop" to remove all excessive spaces. (NOT use string trimming functions and string replacement functions)
For example,
`"    I   Love       PHP"` > `"I Love PHP"`. 
There should be only one space between words.

Any idea?
Thank you

```
$newstr = " "  
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s), $i++ )  
{  
    $newstr = $newstr.substr($s, $i, 1);  
    if (substr($s, $i, 1) == " ")  
        while(substr($s, $i + 1, 1) == " ")  
            $i++;  
}  

print ("  test    test test ")
?>
```

Comment: [ask]. Don’t ask for “ideas”, describe what problem you have with what you tried instead.

Comment: Why did you tag this `python` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove excess whitespace from within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-excess-whitespace-from-within-a-string)

Comment: @GabrielLee All the answers there use built-in functions that he's not allowed to use.

Comment: FYI, `substr($s, $i, 1)` can be simplified to `$s[$i]`.

Comment: Why do you print `"  test    test test "` at the end instead of `$newstr`? Why do you initialize `$newstr` with a single space instead of an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `for` statement, it should be `;` before `$i++`.

You need to start by skipping over all spaces at the beginning of the input string.

Any spaces at the end of the string will be compressed to a single space, you need to check for that and remove it.

```
<?php 
$newstr = "";
$s = "       I   Love     PHP   ";
$len = strlen($s);
// skip over initial spaces
while ($i < $len && $s[$i] == " ") {
  $i++; 
}
for (; $i < $len; $i++ )  
{  
  $newstr .= $s[$i];  
  if ($s[$i] == " ") { 
    while($i < $len-1 && $s[$i+1] == " ") {
      $i++;
    }
  }
}
if ($newstr[strlen($newstr)-1] == " ") {
  // remove trailing space
  $newstr = substr($newstr, 0, strlen($newstr)-1);
}
var_dump($newstr);
```